# Haskell-Project Euler 4

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell and i thought that to get a hang of writing haskell programs,i might solve some project euler problems.

So i went on with it and implemented the problem number 4 of Project Euler.

The problem Statement:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

But there seems to be something wrong with my solution.

Here it is:

```
projectEuler4 :: (Ord a,Num a) => a 

projectEuler4 = max palindromeList
  where palindromeList = [reverse(x*y)|x<-[1..999],y <- [1..999]]
```

GHCI gives me this error:

```
ProjectEuler4.hs:2:17:
Could not deduce (a ~ ([[a0]] -> [[a0]]))
from the context (Ord a, Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             projectEuler4 :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
  at ProjectEuler4.hs:1:18-35
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for projectEuler4 :: (Ord a, Num a) => a
      at ProjectEuler4.hs:1:18
In the return type of a call of `max'
Probable cause: `max' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: max palindromeList
In an equation for `projectEuler4':
    projectEuler4
      = max palindromeList
      where
          palindromeList
            = [reverse (x * y) | x <- [1 .. 1000], y <- [1 .. 1000]]
```

I dont know what this means and am frustrated for not finding the reason for the error.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

---

So After reading some of the answers and comments, 
i did something like This:

```
projectEuler4 :: (Ord a,Num a) => a 
projectEuler4 = max' palindromeList
    where palindromeList = [reverse(show(x*y))|x<-[1..999],y <- [1..999]]

max' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
max' [] = error "Empty List"
max' [p] = p
max' (p:ps) = max p (max' ps)
```

Still doesn't work.

---

OK..

BY following @bheklilr's advice, i changed my program:

```
products :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
products ns ms = [x * y | x <- ns, y <- ms]

isPalindrome :: Integer -> Bool
isPalindrome n = let s = show n in s == reverse s

palindromes :: [Integer]
palindromes = maximum filter (isPalindrome "") (products [100..999] [100..999])
```

Now what do i put in place of the inverted comma? I am seriously confused.

Comment: It could have something to do with how you've written `max(palindromeList)`. Try `max palindromList`, without the parentheses. Haskell doesn't use C-style calling conventions.

Comment: @Eric the two expressions are equivalent. parens are used for grouping, no harm in writing `(((5))) + 4` :)

Comment: So is there any problem with the type classes?

Comment: You're going to need a Haskell tutorial to get started. `max` works on two numbers, not a list (though it would be reasonable to work on lists as well). You can find out information like this using GHCi `:t max`, or using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Comment: @WillNess I thought not having a space between the function and the arguments would cause a problem, but I see it does not. Today I learned...

Comment: @BhavyaSrivastava The `filter` function is what we call "a higher-order function".  It takes a function as its argument and uses that function in a particular way.  The function it takes as its first argument has to have the type `a -> Bool`, where the second argument is a list of type `[a]`.  It applies the predicate to each element in the list, so something like `filter even [1..10]` would return `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` (FYI `even :: Integer -> Bool`).  Also, you need a `$` in between `maximum` and `filter`.

Comment: I got my answer..Thanks..I actually solved it by modifying the code you gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first big error is that you're calling

```
reverse (x * y)
```

Since `x * y` is a number, and `reverse` only works on lists, this won't compile.  You can convert the number to a `String` (which is a list) with `show`:

```
reverse $ show $ x * y
```

However, reversing the string is not what you really want to do, you want to filter find all the palindromes, so you need to filter your list of `(x * y)`s by a predicate.  Instead you could write

```
palindromeList = [z | x <- [1..999], y <- [1..999], let z = x * y, if show z == reverse (show z)]
```

But since this marches off the side of the screen, I would recommend breaking it up into smaller functions

```
-- Generates all products
products :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
products ns ms = [x * y | x <- ns, y <- ms]

-- Checks if a number is a palindrome
isPalindrome :: Integer -> Bool
isPalindrome n = let s = show n in s == reverse s

-- Generates problem-specific palindromes
palindromes :: [Integer]
palindromes = ??? -- Implementation here.  Hint: filter
```

The next big problem is because you're using the `max` function, which has the type

```
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

But we really want to find the max of a list, so we turn to `maximum`, which has the type

```
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

So you can finalize your program as

```
projectEuler4 :: Integer
projectEuler4 = maximum palindromes
```

One final thought: the problem says that you need to find the largest palindrome that is a multiple of 2 three-digit numbers, but your range that you're looking over is `[1..999]`, which includes 1 and 2 digit numbers.  What could you do to not check those?  Conveniently, it'll make the program faster.

Answer (score 4):

```
Prelude> :t max
max :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a
```

That's the type of `max`. When you call it on some argument of type `a`, you get a result of type `a -> a` - a function. That is because `max` is normally called with two values; partial application results in a function which still waits for the second argument before calculating the result, the biggest of two values.

The error shows that Haskell has deduced the type of `palindromeList` as `[[a0]]` so the result's type is `[[a0]] -> [[a0]]`. You gave it as `(Ord a,Num a) => a` and Haskell can't match the two.

What you intended was to use `maximum`, which processes a list and finds the biggest value in it:

```
Prelude> :t maximum
maximum :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
```

The definition of `palindromeList` is wrong too. For starters, the numbers from 1 through 99 in `[1..999]` are not triple-digit numbers. Then you need to test them. `reverse (x*y)` of course is wrong: `reverse :: [a] -> [a]` but result of multiplication of two numbers is a number, *but* - this is still not a test even when you fix it.

A test is something like `show (x*y) == reverse (show (x*y))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reverse a number with:

```
reverse(x*y)
```

`reverse` only works on lists. Fortunately, a `String` is a list, and `show` is the canonical way to create the `String` representation of a value.

So try something like:

```
reverse (show (x*y))
```

Comment: true, but not the reason for the error message given. which will remain (similar), when this is fixed. :)

Comment: Yeah..the messages didnt change.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find the largest product of two three-digit numbers that is palindromic. The program will generate a list of palindromic numbers and find the maximum of that list. The first step is to generate the terms of the product, call them *x* and *y*. This is accomplished using the generators `x <- [100..999]` and `y <- [x..999]`. Note that if we are considering a particular value of *x*, we only need to consider values of *y* that are greater than or equal to *x*; if not, we repeat ourselves. Next, we need to determine whether *xy* is palindromic. The easiest way to accomplish this is to convert *xy* into a string, call it *s*, and then check whether `reverse s == s` holds. To do this, use `show :: Show a = a -> String`. The maximum of the generated list can be found with the function `maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a`.

```
euler4 :: Integral a => a
euler4 = maximum [ x * y | x <- [100..999], y <- [x..999], palindromic (x * y) ]
  where palindromic n = show n == reverse (show n)
```

There are several problems with your code. First, `projectEuler4` should be an integer value, and all integer values are already instances of `Ord` and `Num`. The correct constraint is `Integral a => a`. This will give the choice of `Int` or `Integer`. Second, `max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a` gives the maximum of two members of the `Ord` type class, rather than the maximum of the elements of a list Third, `reverse :: [a] -> [a]` operates on lists, not numeric values; you will need to convert `x * y` to a `String` before applying it to `reverse`. Fourth, `y <- [999]` means that `y` is is generated from the singleton list containing just `999`, not the list of numbers from `x` to `999` or `100` to `999`.

The Haskell tutorial at [haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html) has a good overview of list comprehensions. I would also look for overviews of the Haskell type system, and learn to use the interactive GHC environment - especially the command `:t` (if you're unsure about a function's type and unfamiliar with the standard library).